# Auto-generate class roster from enrollment sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**Scenario:** I'm doing some pro-bono work for a school that has a summer camp enrollment spreadsheet, similar to the table labelled "Example Source":

[image: Example Source]

In order to maintain accurate attendance, the school wants a per-class roster that each teacher can use to determine who's expected to be in attendance on a given day. This can be error-prone because, unlike in my example, the real source has dozens of classes.

In past years, they've manually generated the roster for each class by creating separate docs for each class and hand-typing the student names based on the enrollment sheet. My goal is to automate this process — in Google Sheets *or* Excel, but pref. G Sheets — in order to save the staff time and typos.

The x/X/o entries shown in the sample data is meant to account for the high likelihood of inconsistent data entry…ideally, any non-blank entry on the left should result in the student's name appearing on the right.

**Question**

Given the [sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P4N31qy5dhXDqu_zAZrVCXxHa_Y3UDzBvnTbp36BouM/edit?usp=sharing), how can I automatically populate columns G:I, accounting human data entry inconsistencies as represented by the x/X/o in columns B:D?

Comment: what is the exact logic of `x` / `X` and `O` ?? because in column `I` there should be only `Baz`... how come that `Bar` is there too?

Comment: Have you considered index() with match(), at least i would use those in excel, and I do something similar in my sheets.

Comment: @player0 I wanted to demonstrate that an exact match for, say, "X" is undesirable here because some users may forget to capitalize the X, some might accidentally add in a space without realizing it, etc. Your solution seems to handle this problem nicely, so thanks!

Comment: @SolarMike I haven't used index() or match() before. If player0's solution doesn't do the trick, I'll look into those more deeply. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could either do simple mirror mapping like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4:D<>"", A4:A, ))
```

[image: 0]

or something more compact like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SORT(IF(B4:B<>"", A4:A, )),
               SORT(IF(C4:C<>"", A4:A, )),
               SORT(IF(D4:D<>"", A4:A, ))})
```

[image: 0]